# How to insert logo in exam document class?

Tags: graphics, titles, exam, logos

I would like to insert a logo for the exam questionnaire on the upper right where the title is placed but i dont know how.. i would like to appear it this way.

Comment: Perhaps you are now familiar with the MWE. Can you give us one? You can try `textpos` package and/or the ever-useful `tikz` package, too.

Answer (score 9):

As hpesoj626 said in a comment, `textpos` and `tikz` are classical approaches to put a picture at an absolute position inside a page (i.e: at top right, or at (-1cm,-1cm) being the top right corner of the page the origin, and so on).

But in this case I want to suggest a different and a bit "hackish" approach. Instead of putting the logo at an absolute position, your sample image suggest that it could be put also relative to the School Name (say for example, 3cm at the right and 1cm below of the school name). In this case no additional packages are required, standard LaTeX picture environment can do it. The trick is to define a picture of zero size so that it does not affect the centering of the titles. This is a MWE document which shows how.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\LOGO{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)\unitlength=1cm
\put (3,-1) {\includegraphics[width=5em]{star.mps}}
\end{picture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \sffamily\bfseries
  {\Large School Name}\LOGO\\
  College Name\\
  Department Name\\
  First Semester SY 2012-2013
\end{center}

\hrulefill\par
Etc...

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: Result]