# Logo towards the left

Tags: exam, logos

In the following code, how to put a logo to the left keeping the content under the title still centered and at the same level as the logo. Appreciate any suggestions.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam} 

\noprintanswers
%\printanswers

\pointsinmargin 
%\pointsinrightmargin
%\bracketedpoints
\boxedpoints
%\noboxedpoints

\parindent=0pt 
\title{UNIVERSITY OF MALTA\\FACULTY OF SCIENCE \vspace{-1em}}
\author{Department of Mathematics\\B.SC.(Hons.) YEAR 1\\January 2013 Examination Session\\MAT1511 Analytical Geometry \qquad January 25, 2016}
\date{11.45 a.m. - 1.45 p.m }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Answer THREE QUESTIONS
\hrule


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just by using the `\includegraphics{}` and positioning at the desired location with respect to the center,

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\noprintanswers
%\printanswers

\pointsinmargin 
%\pointsinrightmargin
%\bracketedpoints
\boxedpoints
%\noboxedpoints
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102066/how-to-insert-logo-in-exam-document-class
\parindent=0pt 
\title{\begin{picture}(0,0)\unitlength=1cm
    \put (-5,-1) {\includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a}}
    \end{picture}UNIVERSITY OF MALTA\\FACULTY OF SCIENCE \vspace{-1em}}
\author{Department of Mathematics\\B.SC.(Hons.) YEAR 1\\January 2013 Examination Session\\MAT1511 Analytical Geometry \qquad January 25, 2016}
\date{11.45 a.m. - 1.45 p.m }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Answer THREE QUESTIONS
\hrule


\end{document}
```

you can get:

[image]

with `\put ({x}, {y})` you can define the `x-y` coordinates of the logo's location.